Spring Boot Controller HTTP Post Request test returns a MockHttpServletResponse that is has an empty body, despite a 200 status code
When running the test, no data is being returned if the controller calls notesService.save(). It is simply returning a MockHttpServletResponse with status=200, Error Message=null and Body= (it's just whitespace).
It returns a JSON object if the Note object is returned directly from the Controller class, but it needs to work when notesService.save() is used.
@WebMvcTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class NotesControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private NotesService notesService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    public void testSave() throws Exception {

        Note noteToCreate = new Note(null, "Sample Note", "Hello, World!");
        Note createdNote = new Note(1L, "Sample Note", "Hello, World!");

        when(notesService.save(noteToCreate)).thenReturn(createdNote);

        ResultActions response = mockMvc.perform( post("/api/notes")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(noteToCreate))
        );

        response.andDo(print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/notes")
public class NotesController {

    @Autowired
    private NotesService notesService;

    @PostMapping
    public Note save (@RequestBody Note note ){

        return notesService.save(note);
    }
}


@Service
public class NotesService {

    public Note save(Note note){
        return new Note(1L, "Sample Note", "Hello, World!");
    }
}

